# JPA @OneToMany by default is not so Lazy and fetch everything

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, jpa, ejb, openjpa

Current project runs on Spring + Openjpa + Roo. I have an entity like this

```
public class Zoo{
    ....
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="zoo", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
    private List<Elephant> elephants;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="zoo", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
    private List<Jaguar> jaguars;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="zoo", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
    private List<Tiger> tigers;
    ....
}
```

Then I have a simple UI page just trying to update the Zoo name, however from SQL trace log after the simple query

```
SELECT t0.id, t0.name 
FROM Zoo t0 
WHERE t0.id = ?
```

there are a query like this

```
SELECT * FROM Zoo, Tiger, TigerProduct, TigerFood, FoodSupplier, SupplierContacts...
```

and a hundreds queries like this:

```
SELECT * FROM TigerProduct where tiger.id =: id_1
.....
SELECT * FROM TigerProduct where tiger.id =: id_n
....
....
SELECT * FROM TigerFood where tiger.id =: id_1
....
SELECT * FROM TigerFood where tiger.id =: id_n
```

And same to Jaguar and Elephant as well. This makes this simple action really slow when there is large amount of data resides in the database.

The java code for the first query and the ones after is pretty simple:

```
public static Zoo findZoo(Long id) {
    if (id == null) return null;
    return entityManager().find(Zoo.class, id);
}
```

from above it looks like the default `FetchType.Lazy` on `@OneToMany` relation is not so lazy at all that JPA tries to pull all data on the chain.

So what's going on and how to clear this situation? I only prefer to have the first query and that's it

Comment: I didn't understand: does `entityManager().find(Zoo.class, id)` run also all those queries? Have you tried to specify explicitly the `FetchType.LAZY` (don't think will help) ? Have you tried to downgrade/upgrade OpenJPA (because it seems to me like a performance problem in that implementation)?

Comment: @Andrei I Yes in the java code I do specify the FetchType.LAZY, but it doesn't help like you expected. And you are also correct that no one is happy on that simple request on the UI wait for one minutes to return result. Our openjpa is already the latest... but I cannot find any threads or articles mention about this kind of behavior anywhere, make me feels like I have a bug in the application but not to OpenJPA.

Comment: So you get the same behavior when you call `em.find()`?  Have you tried of downgrading OpenJPA?

Comment: Post the contents of your persistence.xml.

Answer (score 1):

`FetchType.Lazy` is only a hint, and not a requirement, as the documentation says. So you cannot rely on this behavior, you can only hope that your JPA provider respects your hint. Also JPA does not forces a way how the JPQL queries or entitymanager calls are converted to SQL code, so it is somehow our duty to select a JPA provider+version that knows how to do things better (as we define what better means). This was probably a decision that should encourage the competition between JPA providers.

Comment: The idea behind this answer: it is a problem of the JPA implementation (OpenJPA in this case), as JPA itself does not have control over such behaviors.

Comment: -1 because your answer does not help answer the question. You stated a fact that doesn't help get to the bottom of the behavior that the op is observing. This is most likely a problem with the usage of OpenJPA, not an implementation bug.

Comment: It is not the purpose of downvote. About the problem, replace find call with JPA query.